# HTML input text box very small

Tags: html, css

I'm coding this little pricing script and I would like the user to be able to enter a number value into an HTML text input box. 
You can see this script here: https://www.counterboosting.com/input-box-problem/
And under "select number of wins" and "Price: -" you can see a small white box.

This is the code for the box:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" value="1"  size="100">
```

No matter what size I enter, it is always show small like that. Note that the box shows correctly on small browser sizes such as phones or tablets, or if you decrease your browser width. When you increase the browser width it snaps back into small form like that. Does anyone know the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this input inside of a bootstrap row, which is inside another row. Try making the column larger.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-5">
```

Comment: Also, don't use `size` with columns.  Bootstrap should take care of that with CSS.

Comment: hm so adding the col-md-5 actually fixed the box problem but broke the javascript. I don't know why, do you have an idea why that would happen?

Comment: nevermind, gave you the answer, fixed everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this, one is using width instead of size in percentage.
    `<input type="text" id="amount" value="1"  width="80%">` 
This will set the width with respect to the div or span inside which the input is defined. 
Alternately, you can define a textarea with 1 row and increase the number of columns to increase the width 
    `<textarea rows="1" cols="40" id="amount" name="amount" value="1"></textarea>`